# Finding all left inverse of a matrix B

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

Let
$$
\mathbf{B} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
1 & -3 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right].
$$

My task at hand is to all left-inverse matrices of $\mathbf{B}$, without using the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse.

**My attempt** so far is the following:
I would like to solve the equation $\mathbf{X}\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{I}$ i.e
$$
\left[\begin{array}{lll}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \\
x_4 & x_5 & x_6
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
1 & -3 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right]  =\left[\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
I do this by solving the system

$$
[\mathbf{B}^{\top}|\mathbf{I}] = \left[\begin{array}{ccc|cc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$

By doing rowoperations I get the following RREF
$$
\left[\begin{array}{lll|ll}
1 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$

Hence $x_1 = 3, x_2=1, x_3 = s, x_4=1, x_5=0, x_6=t$ where $s$ and $t$ are free variables i.e there are **infinitely many solutions** and all left-inverses can be described by the matrix

$$
\left[\begin{array}{lll}
3 & 1 & s  \\
1 & 0 & t 
\end{array}\right]
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: I would say yes

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is totally correct.

A non-square matrix has always a side-inverse (in this case a left-inverse) if it has full rank. However, the side-inverse does not have to be unique.

Actually I think that a side-invertible non-square matrix has always several side-inverses (maybe an infinite number). The proof of this can be an interesting exercise to do.

**Edit**: my intuition was wrong. Thanks to the comment below, we know that a matrix has several left inverses if it has more rows than columns, and it has zero left inverses if it has more columns than rows.

Comment: The matrix has several left inverses if it has more rows than columns, and it has zero left inverses if it has more columns than rows.

Comment: Great comment! Thank you for the information.